# Is it a bad practice to access a class's constant via an instance?

Tags: php

```
class A {
    const FOO = 'bar';
}

$a = new A();


// 1.
echo A::FOO;

// 2.
echo $a::FOO;
```

Is option 1. or 2. cleaner or is it equal?

Comment: Both work, both are legal, both have their uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that `A::FOO` will always refer to a very specific, unchanging constant. Which value `$a::FOO` refers to depends on what `$a` is, which may change. This allows you to subclass `A` and override `FOO` in that subclass. In general, `$a::FOO` allows more "duck-typing" style programming instead of hardcoding class names. It's therefore not a bad idea at all.

Whether overriding constants in subclasses is a brilliant idea is a different topic, but it can have its uses if applied carefully.